# Why is the AngularJS binding not working even though the $scope property is getting updated?

Tags: angularjs, binding, angularjs-scope

I am new to AngularJS and am struggling to get the binding down. In the simple example below, I'm trying to update the UI to show the value of the jquery slider (I understand there is a pure Angular way to solve this, but this is just my reduction test case, and it would still be very helpful for me to understand why changing `$scope.slider_value` does not update the view). What am I missing?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/flick/jquery-ui.css" />        
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var testApp = angular.module('testApp', []);
            testApp.controller('testCtrl', function($scope) {
                $('#slider').slider({
                    max: 1000,
                    slide: function( event, ui ) {
                        $scope.slider_value = ui.value;
                    }
                });
                $scope.slider_value = 0;
            });

        </script>
        <style>
            #slider { margin: 20px; }
            #to_update { margin: 10px; font-family: Arial; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="testApp">
        <div ng-controller="testCtrl">
            <div id="slider"></div>
            <div id="to_update">slider value: {{ slider_value }}</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are updating the scope via an event angular does not know about.  In this case, you need to wrap the updates in a `$apply`.

Try this:

```
slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        $scope.slider_value = ui.value;
    });
}
```

Check out the documentation on [scope.$apply](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24apply)

Comment: This is a viable solution to the question, but since a desire to learn was also expressed... The logic to access the DOM should be handled via directives, and not via controllers. This allows the controllers to be more modular and testable (same w/ the directives). Consider making a directive named slider where you can encapsulate the jQuery logic/implementation.

Comment: @Brocco, agreed - I need to ultimately wrap this in a directive. Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: @NG., Thanks - this is what I was missing.